# hiding one form and displaying another with a button

Tags: javascript, css, forms, button, hta

I have multiple forms in one html. The CSS for those forms hides all but the first (form1) there is a button on each form that saves the form and I would like it to then show the next form (form2) only. And so on and so forth. I apologize in advance for not displaying my code. I have no internet except for on my phone. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not use .hide and .show in jquery?

Comment: A phone is not really the best way to convey code, I agree, but that just means you should wait until you have access to a more powerful computer before posting your question. Stack Overflow questions *need* to have code to be answerable; otherwise, they're just too broad.

Comment: Understood my apologies. I will get that corrected as soon as I can. Thank you sir.

Comment: Keep a habit of pasting code here to get solve your issue in better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
$("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
$("p").show();
});
```

You can use button onclick event

You can refer [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)